# Maven not recognizing integration tests in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm trying to set up integration testing for my multi-module Maven project using the failsafe plugin.
In a smaller dummy project, I had the following structure:

```
pom.xml
src 
-main
--java
---com
----App.java
-test
--java 
---com 
----AppIT.java
```

Here was the relevant addition to the pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>failsafe</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.0</version>
          <executions>
             <execution>
               <goals>
                 <goal>integration-test</goal>
                 <goal>verify</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Everything worked fine and the test was detected when I ran `mvn verify -Pfailsafe`.

[image]

For the new project, I have the following
structure:

```
pom.xml
module-1
module-2
module-testing
-src
--test
---java    
----com
-----Test1.java
-----Test2.java
-----...
-----RestIT.java
```

All of Test1.java through TestN.java are unit tests. RestIT.java is the name of an empty integration test which I just want to be
detected by the verify command in the same way that AppIT.java was detected in the old dummy project.

Here is what I added to the pom.xml for the entire project (identical to what was in the pom.xml for the dummy Maven project):

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>failsafe</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
 </profiles>
```

The existing unit tests are detected in the output of `mvn verify -Pfailsafe`, but the RestIT.java test is not. I've also
previously seen the error for "the profile of failsafe not found" before and it's not present when I run that command
with the above snippet added to the parent pom.xml.

If you're interested in seeing the entire maven command output or the whole pom.xml let me know and I'll add Dropbox links.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the module(s) with integration tests:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>failsafe</id> 
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Note, the ID is the same. I suspect this will allow the module to pick up the profile contents. Profiles are not inherited by default.